# .netcore EF linq - this is a BUG? Very strange behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[image]I have two table in sql. Document and User. Document have relation to User and I want to get users that I sent document recently.

I need to sort by the date document was sent and get unique (distinct) user with relation to this document

This is my linq queries

```
var recentClients = documentCaseRepository.Entities
            .Where(docCase => docCase.AssignedByAgentId == WC.UserContext.UserId)
            .OrderByDescending(userWithDate => userWithDate.LastUpdateDate)
            .Take(1000) // I need this because if I comment this line then EF generate completely different sql query. 
            .Select(doc => new { doc.AssignedToClient.Id, doc.AssignedToClient.FirstName, doc.AssignedToClient.LastName })                
            .Distinct()
            .Take(configuration.MaxRecentClientsResults)                
            .ToList();
```

and generated sql query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) [t].*
FROM (
     SELECT TOP(1000) [docCase.AssignedToClient].[Id]
     FROM [DocumentCase] AS [docCase]
     INNER JOIN [User] AS [docCase.AssignedToClient] 
       ON ([docCase].[AssignedToClientId] = [docCase.AssignedToClient].[Id])
     WHERE [docCase].[AssignedByAgentId] = 3
     ORDER BY [docCase].[LastUpdateDate] DESC
) 
AS [t]
```

Every thing is correct for now. But if I delete this line

```
.Take(1000) // I need this because...
```

EF generated completely different query such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) 
    [docCase.AssignedToClient].[Id]
FROM [DocumentCase] AS [docCase]
INNER JOIN [User] AS [docCase.AssignedToClient] 
    ON ([docCase].[AssignedToClientId] = [docCase.AssignedToClient].[Id])
WHERE [docCase].[AssignedByAgentId] = 3
```

My question is: why EF not generated orderby clause and subquery with distinct? 
This is a BUG EF or I'm doing something wrong? And what I must do to generate in linq this sql query ()

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 [t].*
FROM ( SELECT [docCase.AssignedToClient].[Id]
 FROM [DocumentCase] AS [docCase]
 INNER JOIN [User] AS [docCase.AssignedToClient] 
   ON [docCase].[AssignedToClientId] = [docCase.AssignedToClient].[Id]
 WHERE [docCase].[AssignedByAgentId] = 1
 ORDER BY [docCase].[LastUpdateDate] DESC
) AS [t]
```

Comment: You might get better answers if you format that SQL in a way that the differences are obvious to readers without scrolling.

Comment: In addition, as we don't know your tables and contents, can you explain if and why the other statement is wrong or not usable for you? Does it produce different results you did not expect?

Comment: @nvoigt I edit my question and add more information.

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy` information not always retained across other operators such as `Distinct`. Entity Framework does not document (to my knowledge) how exactly `OrderBy` is propagated.

This kind of makes sense because some operators have undefined output order. The fact that ordering is retained in many situations is a convenience for the developer.

Move the `OrderBy` to the end of the query (or at least past the `Distinct`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the difference in queries is that `Distinct` messes up result order. So when you first execute `OrderBy` and then `Distinct`, you can just es well not execute `OrderBy`, because this order is lost anyway. So EF can just optimize it away.

Calling `Take` in between causes the result set to be semantically different: You first order the items, take the first 1000 items *of that order* and then call `Distinct` on them.

What you can change in your query depends mainly on the result you want to achieve. Maybe you want to first make the result set distinct then order by date and finally take the amount of items. Other options are also thinkable based on your requirements.

Comment: Ok but how I can build linq query to generate sql like this: --- I added example in my question for better formatting ---

Comment: @stitch7c0 it seems what you want is the sequence `distinct -> orderby -> take`.